Is there a good principle of virtual work (PVW) solution to this problem from the Feynman Lectures Exercises?
Is there a good way to treat this problem using the principle of virtual work (PVW)?  I'm not sure if we are supposed to use the PVW in this particular instance.  In many places the authors do encourage the student to use the PVW to work problems.

B-7. An ornament for a courtyard at a World's Fair is to be made up of four identical, frictionless metal spheres, each weighing $2\sqrt{6}$ ton-wts. The spheres are to be arranged as shown, with three resting on a horizontal surface and touching each other; the fourth is to rest freely on the other three. The bottom three are kept from separating by spot welds at the points of contact with each other. Allowing for a factor of safety of 3, how much tension must the spot welds withstand?

I came up with a formula relating virtual displacements to change in energy and varied the spacing between the spheres.  Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be very enlightening despite giving the correct answer.
Adding my original solution
I posted this as an answer, but decided to move it to the question.

I'm just posting this to show others my "not very enlightening" solution using the PVW.
Call $r$ the distance from the center of one of the base spheres
to the center of mass of the base. The distance between the sphere
centers defaults to $\ell_{o}=2$. Our method is to calculate the
change in height due to a virtual displacement of all three base spheres,
changing $\ell$ between base sphere centers but maintaining $\ell_{o}=2$
for the base sphere to cap sphere center distances. Since we are assuming
uniform increases in the sides $\ell$ the base triangle remains isosceles.
Since the slant height from a base sphere center to the cap sphere
center is a fixed $\ell_{o}=2$ and the center of the cap sphere is
directly above the tail of the red vector , Pythagoras gives us the
height. We differentiate to get the relationship $\sqrt{6}dh=-d\ell.$
We can then replace all the $\ell$ with $\ell_{o}$ and factor it
out. The factor of 3 in $3\mathbf{t}d\ell$ appears because all 3 of the $\ell$ in the base
are virtually varied. Finally we multiply by the over-design factor
to obtain the tension $\tau.$
\begin{align*}
r= & \frac{\ell}{2}\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{\ell}{\sqrt{3}}\\
\ell_{o}^{2}= & h^{2}+r^{2}=h^{2}+\frac{\ell^{2}}{3}\\
h= & \frac{\sqrt{3\ell_{o}^{2}-\ell^{2}}}{\sqrt{3}}\\
\frac{dh}{d\ell}= & -\frac{\ell_{o}}{\sqrt{3}\sqrt{3\ell_{o}^{2}-\ell_{o}^{2}}}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\\
3\mathbf{t}d\ell= & Wdh=2\sqrt{6}dh=-2\sqrt{6}\frac{d\ell}{\sqrt{6}}\\
\mathbf{t}= & -\frac{2}{3}\\
\tau= & -2\text{ ton-wt}
\end{align*}



This is not signally different from the solution I already had.  It's just a bit more direct.  I'm gonna hold off accepting it to see if someone else comes up with a "that's the right way" solution.  The first two images are what I used to work out the necessary relationships.  The third image depicts the variation.
Let $D$ be the diameter of the balls which is also the center-to-center
distance in the static configuration. In this configuration the ball
centers lie on the vertices of a regular tetrahedron with edge length
$D.$ Our approach will be to vary the horizontal circle of radius
$R$holding the center of the base fixed. That is, each of the balls
in the base is moved radially a distance $\delta R$ in the plane
of the base triangle.
Call the edge of the base triangle $s$ which is initially $s_{o}=D.$
Due to the symmetry of the variation, the proportion $\sqrt{3}=D/R_{o}=s/R$
is preserved. The virtual work done by the calculated tension $\mathbf{t}$
is $\delta w=3\mathbf{t}\delta s.$ The factor of 3 appears because
there are three displacements $\delta s=\sqrt{3}\delta R$ with calculated
tension $\mathbf{t}.$ The principle of virtual work says $\delta w=W\delta h=3\mathbf{t}\delta s=\tau\delta s$
where we use the stipulated over-design factor $\tau=3\mathbf{t}.$
The height of the top center above the base plane is $h=\sqrt{D^{2}-R^{2}}$
which is initially $h_{o}=R_{o}\sqrt{2}.$ Puting it all together
gives
\begin{align*}
\tau= & W\frac{\delta h}{\delta s}=2\sqrt{6}\frac{\delta h}{\delta s}\\
\delta h= & -\frac{R_{o}}{h_{o}}\delta R=-\frac{\delta s}{\sqrt{6}}\\
\tau= & -2\text{ ton-wt}
\end{align*}



